# Resnet50 image resize and preprocessing issue

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, opencv, python

I am resizing the images and passing it through keras resnet50 preprocessing, and saving the output to a numpy array as below

```
image_height_cnn = 256
image_width_cnn = 256

for i in range(len(category_data)):
    image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(src_dir, 'Original Demo', category_data.iloc[i][0])) 
    

    
    image_cnn = cv2.resize(image, (image_height_cnn, image_width_cnn))
    image_landmarks = cv2.resize(image, (image_height_landmarks, image_width_landmarks))

    img = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input(image_cnn)
        images.append(image_cnn)
    np.save('train_test' + '/' + category + '/images_test.npy', images)


plt.imshow(train_images_test[24], interpolation= 'nearest')
```

I get the below output
[image]

The image does not seem to be resized to 256 x 256, any ideas!!

Comment: Your code is extremely inconsistent.

Comment: I'd simplify and double check resizing works as expected with the images and opencv alone, removing resnet at this stage until the bug is fixed. The cv2.resize dimensions argument is in width, height order, however it shouldn't affect you since they are the same. Double check the original image as well just to make sure it doesn't have a white border for any reason. (I'd expect if the resize to be wrong for the content to at least be in the top left corner. it's a bit strange the plot shows white pixels on top, right and bottom, but not left).

Comment: I tried resizing manually a few pics and they worked fine. Not sure what happens when I run the for loop @GeorgeProfenza

Comment: Could you check all of them, in case there are some odd images in your dataset for any reason ? Also remember you're plotting images from the `train_images_test` list, however the resized images are stored in the `images` list (as far as I can tell in the snippet above)